# minima and maxima of a voltage signal

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, maxima-minima

I wanted some help on how to approach on finding the minima and maxima of the following equation:

v(t)= $(t-2t^2)*e^{-0.5*|t|}$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: for what stands $t$ here?

Comment: What your thoughts on that? Which approach you thought and where you got stuck?

Comment: t stands for time

Comment: well i differentiated ended up with $e^{-0.5*|t|}*(t-4t) - \frac{0.5e^{-0.5*|t|}*t(t-2t^2)}{|t|}$ But i am not too sure on how to approach on getting the minima and maxima.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Differentiating with respect to $ t $ and equating with 0, you have:

$$ (t-2t^2) . e^{-0.5 |t|} . (-0.5) \frac {t}{|t|} + e^{-0.5 |t|} . (1-4t) = 0$$

$$ => e^{-0.5 |t|} (-\frac {t}{2|t|} (t - 2t^2 ) +1 - 4t) = 0$$

Since there is no real solution of $ e^x = 0 $, so we can say:
$$ -t^2 + 2t^3 + 2|t| - 8t|t| = 0$$

You solve the equation to get values of $ t $ and check if those values give maxima or minima value in the function by taking double derivative of $ t $ .

Comment: when solving for t do i treat $|t|$ the same as $t$

Comment: No. Derivative of $|t|$ is $\frac {t} {|t|}$ which gives +1 or - 1 depending on value of t